# Locus of equilibrium points ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we consider the ODE $x' - x = 0$, how can we compute the vector field of the associated planar system and draw its locus of equilibrium points in the phase line?

So, one way I see is that $x = x$', and why I need to associate in terms of $x$, but cant seem to get far on this. I know we need some eigenvector.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets use two methods to look at this:

**Method 1: Direct Solution:**

$$\tag 1 \frac{dx}{dt} = x, x(0) = x_0$$

We can easily solve this:

$$\tag 2 \frac{dx}{x} = dt \rightarrow x(t) = x_0e^{t}, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$$

We can see sample solutions for varying $x_0$ using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%27+-+x+%3D+0).

**Method 2: Phase Portrait**

We notice that the system is autonomous, so every cross section for a fixed $t$ will have the same profile. Otherwise, we just notice that, based on the sign of $x$, we have:

- $(1) ~x \gt 0 \Longrightarrow$ positively sloped arrow (more positive the higher we go)
- $(2) ~ x = 0 \Longrightarrow$ no slope (horizontal arrows)
- $(3) ~ x \lt 0 \Longrightarrow$ negatively sloped arrows (more negative the further down we go)

You can overlay the exact solution from "Method 1" onto this phase portrait to compare them and use some program to draw it.

If we had a system of equations, we could use the eignevalues, eigenvectors and phase portraits.

We could also use dynamical systems approach and the phase line.

Is that all clear.

Regards

Comment: +1 which one do you suggest me for the students in this problem? Do you think the grade they are in is important?

Comment: @BabakSorouh: I think this is a rare example that can students and teachers can get a lot of mileage from. There are actually at least the four methods above that can be used and each of the approaches gives useful information. All these methods enrich the students toolbox for thinking about and solving problems. Not much time would be needed to teach all four and maybe others! Regards

Comment: Impressive...plus the fact that there are even more approaches!